# ¿Cómo podría combinar ciertos valores de un array en PHP y sumar el valor de otro índice?

Tags: php, array

Estoy obteniendo un array con ciertos valores que yo quisiera combinar en uno solo.

La cuestión es más complicada, pero por lo pronto quisiera saber si hay una forma de combinar en un solo elemento dentro del array, aquellos cuya clave `0` sea igual, ignorando los acentos y las mayúsculas/minúsculas.

Por ejemplo, en el array indicado más abajo, tendría que combinar la clave `0` de los índices `1895, 1897, 1899, 1903, 1904` y al mismo tiempo sumar los valores de la clave `1`.

Esto es un ejemplo de un array mucho más largo, con varios casos así en los que quisiera comparar qué valores son iguales y combinarlos en uno sumando a ese elemento final los números de la clave `1`.

O sea, dado este array:

```
[1895] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-Bienal-biblico-patristico/
        [1] => 1
    )

[1896] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-biblico-patristico/
        [1] => 5
    )

[1897] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-bienal-biblico-patristico
        [1] => 2168
    )

[1898] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-bienal-biblico-patristico-de-la-liturgia-de-las-horas/
        [1] => 252
    )

[1899] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-bienal-biblico-patristico/
        [1] => 53956
    )

[1900] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-bienal-biblico-patristico/undefined
        [1] => 2
    )

[1901] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-bienal-biblico-patris…/
        [1] => 1
    )

[1902] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionário
        [1] => 1
    )

[1903] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionário-bienal-biblico-patristico
        [1] => 1
    )

[1904] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionário-bienal-biblico-patristico/
        [1] => 2
    )
```

Se trataría de obtener el resultado siguiente:

```
[XXXXX] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-bienal-biblico-patristico/
        [1] => 56128
    )
```

Los otros elementos que no coinciden exactamente quedarían como están, por el momento:

```
[1896] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-biblico-patristico/
        [1] => 5
    )

[1898] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-bienal-biblico-patristico-de-la-liturgia-de-las-horas/
        [1] => 252
    )

[1900] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-bienal-biblico-patristico/undefined
        [1] => 2
    )

[1901] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-bienal-biblico-patris…/
        [1] => 1
    )

[1902] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionário
        [1] => 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque la respuesta de @JonnathanQ funciona, he encontrado esta manera de hacerlo usando un solo array y todo dentro del mismo bucle `for`.

La pongo como respuesta por si puede servir a algún otro con una situación similar:

```
    /*Creamos un nuevo array para obtener los datos organizados*/
    $arrNew = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {

        /*
            Aquí podemos normalizar la URL ($row[0]):
              - haciendo que sea toda en minúscula
              - poniéndole / al final cuando no lo tenga
              - quitando las palabras con acento... etc
        */
        $row[0]=strtolower($row[0]);
        if (substr($row[0], -1) != '/') {
            $row[0]=$row[0] . '/';
        }

        /*
            Verificamos con un operador ternario si el valor no está en el nuevo array:
              - si no está lo agregamos
              - si está, le sumamos a $row[1], el valor actual
        */
         (!isset($arrNew[$row[0]])) ? $arrNew[$row[0]] = $row : $arrNew[$row[0]][1] += $row[1];
    }
    /*Ordenamos nuestro nuevo array*/
    $arrNew = array_values($arrNew);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arrNew);
    echo "</pre>";
```

**Output:**

```
[198] => Array
    (
        [0] => /leccionario-bienal-biblico-patristico/
        [1] => 56241
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno lo primero es que recorras el arreglo original e ir armando otro con los totales, al colocar un valor en el nuevo arreglo se debe validar si ya se encuentra la llave (**array_key_exists**), que para tu caso serian la URIs que tienes en el arreglo original, así vas acumulando los valores

```
$arrayTmp = array();
foreach ( $arrayOriginal as $elemento ) {
    if ( array_key_exists($elemento[0],$arrayTmp) ) {
        $arrayTmp[$elemento[0]] += $elemento[1];
    } else {
        $arrayTmp[$elemento[0]] = $elemento[1];
    }
}
```

Luego es necesario transformar la información dado el arreglo temporal anterior no tiene la estructura del arreglo original, entonces se recorre y finalmente en otro arreglo que seria el definitivo se coloca la información tal como el original.

```
$arrayCombinado = array();
foreach ($arrayTmp as $key => $value) {
    array_push($arrayCombinado,array($key,$value));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tu código funciona. Aunque encontré una forma más simple de hacerlo, en un sólo bucle y usando un sólo array.